# Add ranking to joined tables in query

Tags: php, mysql

My working query is:

```
SELECT tulemus.liige_id, liige_v.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, liige_v.Perekonnanimi, punktid, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku FROM tulemus 
INNER JOIN liige_v on tulemus.liige_id = liige_v.liige_id
GROUP BY tulemus.liige_id
order by punktidkokku desc
```

with this compound all results for user id ( liige_id) from table "tulemus",
How can I add the ranking as well for the table of results?

Comment: What you mean by ranking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a variable for this.  For a `group by`, I think it is better to do this using a subquery:

```
SELECT tv.*,
       (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
FROM (SELECT tulemus.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, 
             liige_v.Perekonnanimi, punktid, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku
      FROM tulemus INNER JOIN
           liige_v
           ON tulemus.liige_id = liige_v.liige_id
      GROUP BY tulemus.liige_id
     ) tv CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY punktidkokku desc;
```

Comment: MySQL answer: 

#1060 - Duplicate column name 'liige_id'

Comment: If I changed 'FROM (SELECT tulemus.liige_id, liige_v.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, 
             liige_v.Perekonnanimi, punktid, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku'
to 'FROM (SELECT liige_v.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, 
             liige_v.Perekonnanimi, punktid, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku'
it works as it should

Comment: @Margus . . . I didn't even look at the `select` list, but you had an unnecessary duplicate there -- you know the two values are the same, so you only need one.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
from
(
    SELECT tulemus.liige_id, 
           liige_v.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, liige_v.Perekonnanimi, 
           punktid, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku           
    FROM tulemus 
    INNER JOIN liige_v on tulemus.liige_id = liige_v.liige_id    
    GROUP BY tulemus.liige_id
    order by punktidkokku desc
) tmp
CROSS JOIN (select @rank := 0) r
```

Comment: With this rank works strangely ;) at least some result but not right 
result is : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6495hnjno10ifi9/Screenshot%202015-04-24%2016.22.02.png?dl=0)
and with rank result is : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxz7fpyxs4ensbi/Screenshot%202015-04-24%2016.25.52.png?dl=0)
what I need is results for  "punktidkokku" and ranking with according to these

Comment: figured out right now the rank is the same as table "tulemus" id 
tulemus_id 1= rank 1
tulemus_id 2 = rank 2
etc.